# Import excel file in python and identify cells of which the content is strikethrough

Tags: python, excel, fonts, strikethrough

I want to read in many Excel documents and I would like to receive at least one important bit of information on the format. However, I am afraid that there is no tool for it, so my hope is on you!

Each excel file that I am reading in contains a few cells that of which the content is strikethrough. For those who don't know the word (I didn't know it either), strikethrough means that there is a horizontal line through the content.

I have figured out that I will need to read in my documents with xlrd to be able to identify the fonts. However, I have been going over a list of possibilities and none of them contains a check on strikethrough.

Comment: create a file yourself with two cells, one is just a text second is a same text with strikethrough. Read both with xlrd and compare.

Comment: Try `Font.struck_out`  https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/font.html (Too short for an answer)

Comment: @Alex I will have to do it for 59 excel files with multiple sheets, so I prefer to not do something by hand.

Comment: @JReid I tried, but it is not working.

Comment: It would have to be that or escapement. Strange struck_out seems most likely.

Answer (score 4):

You have to open the workbook with `formatting_info` kwarg as `True`. Then, get `the` XF object of the cells and get the `Font` object. The `struck_out` attribute is what you're looking for. An example:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, formatting_info=True)
sh = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet)
xf = workbook.xf_list[sh.cell_xf_index(row, col)]
font = workbook.font_list[xf.font_index]
if font.struck_out:
    print(row, col)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('xyz.xlsx')
sheet = book.get_sheet_names()[0] #This will consider **Sheet1** of our excel file
ws = book.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.font.strike:
            print(cell.value)
```

Comment: What if I want to get the value of a cell column?